# append to vector using case_when

Tags: r

I have a function, and i want to append to a vector of variables some variables in some specific cases. This later becomes to a regression formuls

Code example:

```
some_function <- function (df,mdl){ 
  
  vars <- c("var1", "var2", "var3")
  vars <- case_when(mdl== "model1" ~ vars<-("var3", "var4", vars),
                    mdl== "model2" ~ vars<-("var4", "var5", vars))
  
  target_col <- "count"
  target_formula <- as.formula(sprintf("%s ~ %s", 
                                       target_col, 
                                       paste(vars, collapse = " + ")))
}
```

mdl is an acronym made of text supposed to represent the different models, there are about 8-10

Comment: Can you show a full example with expected output

Comment: The `case_when` showed is not correct as well.  if 'mdl' is a column name within the data, you may want to use it within `mutate` and the assignment is also not correct `vars<-`

Comment: Don't use `<-` (or assignment in general) *within* `case_when`, there is no place I believe that would be appropriate (or even unambiguous).

Comment: If you have about 8-10 'mdl' conditions, create a key/value list pair and subset with `[[`

Comment: @akrun most keys get the same add on vars, but how do i do what you said?

Comment: Your code `("var3", "var4", vars` seems to be duplicating the 'var3' .  I would create a list i.e. `list(model1 = "var3", model2 = "var5", ...)` and then extract the list with `lst1[[mdl]]` to get those values

Answer (score 0):

You can define `model1`/`model2` in a list, then `map` with `as.formula`:

```r
library(purrr)
library(glue)

vars <- c("var1", "var2", "var3")
target <- "count"
models <- list(model1 = c("var3", "var4", vars),
               model2 = c("var4", "var5", vars))

map(models, ~as.formula(glue("{target} ~ {paste(., collapse = ' + ')}")))
```

Output:

```r
$model1
count ~ var3 + var4 + var1 + var2 + var3
<environment: 0x7fec25b8b770>

$model2
count ~ var4 + var5 + var1 + var2 + var3
<environment: 0x7fecf096b560>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `reformulate` to create the models in `base R`

```
vars <- c("var1", "var2", "var3")
target <- "count"
models <- list(model1 = c("var3", "var4", vars),
           model2 = c("var4", "var5", vars))
lapply(models, reformulate, response = target)
```

-output

```
#$model1
#count ~ var3 + var4 + var1 + var2 + var3
#<environment: 0x7f92c7658ed8>

#$model2
#count ~ var4 + var5 + var1 + var2 + var3
#<environment: 0x7f92c7649a88>
```

---

It can be wrapped in a `function` and use conditions with `if/else` and the dataset input to function seems to be not used in the OP's post

```
some_function <- function (df,mdl){ 

 vars <- c("var1", "var2", "var3")
 vars <- if(mdl == "model1") {
            c(vars, "var4")
    } else c(vars, "var5")
 


 target_col <- "count"
 reformulate(vars, response = target)
}
```

-testing

```
some_function(iris, "model1")
#count ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + var4
#<environment: 0x7f92f0c77370>

some_function(iris, "model2")
#count ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + var5
#<environment: 0x7f92f0ce6db8>
```

Comment: Can this if be replaced with case_when? Or can you show an example for 3-4 models with a list?

Comment: @Stat.Enthus If it is around 8 or 10 cases, I would suggest either to use `switch` or a `list`.   `case_when` requires lengths to be the same and here it is not the case

Answer (score 0):

Don't do assignment within `case_when`, it is almost never a good thing to attempt. Instead, try this:

```r
some_function <- function (df,mdl){ 
  newvars <- dplyr::case_when(
    mdl == "model1" ~ c("var3", "var4"),
    mdl == "model2" ~ c("var4", "var5")
  )
  vars <- c("var1", "var2", "var3", newvars)
  # something else here
  vars
}

some_function(mtcars, "model1")
# [1] "var1" "var2" "var3" "var3" "var4"
some_function(mtcars, "model2")
# [1] "var1" "var2" "var3" "var4" "var5"
```

That seems to be okay, but there are two things that could be improved.

1. The first one repeats `"var3"`, perhaps we can add `vars <- unique(vars)` to the function.
2. `case_when` is really meant to be a vectorized replacement for nested `ifelse` (or `dplyr::if_else`), where nesting *works* but can make things hard to follow/maintain. Because of this, this suggests that `mdl` could be length greater than 1. But when we pass a length-2 argument:

   ```r
   some_function(mtcars, c("model1", "model2"))
   # [1] "var1" "var2" "var3" "var3" "var5"
   ```

   The first comparison in `case_when` finds that `mdl == "model1"` matches the first vector, but it only uses the first of the `c("var3","var4")`. Further, if we pass many more, then we get errors about incompatible vector lengths.

I *suspect* that you are intending `mdl` to be length 1, in which case you likely have several other model numbers and want a set of additional variables to add to the defaults. Perhaps this is ultimately what you want?

```r
some_function <- function (df, mdl){ 
  newvars <- switch(
    mdl[1],
    model1 = c("var3", "var4"),
    model2 = c("var4", "var5"),
    stop("unrecognized model: ", sQuote(mdl))
  )
  vars <- c("var1", "var2", "var3", newvars)
  # something else here
  vars
}

some_function(mtcars, "model1")
# [1] "var1" "var2" "var3" "var3" "var4"
some_function(mtcars, "model2")
# [1] "var1" "var2" "var3" "var4" "var5"
some_function(mtcars, "model3")
# Error in some_function(mtcars, "model3") : unrecognized model: 'model3'
```

Comment: mdl[1] - What does this mean? I plan it to a single string of 3-4 chars..